# Draw image from a buffer in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es, ios4, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently working on an iOS project which is a sort of a client VNC. The server-client connection is successfully established. The program receives the screen image in RAW format and stocks it in a buffer.

My question is how can I draw the buffer in a UIView so that when de buffer is updated so does the view.

I've read the [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW1)

I suppose this is the solution of my problem but I'm really confused. Can someone gives me an example about how to render a buffer in a UIView ? Or if someone has a better solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I create a `CGDataProviderRef` and a 'CGImageRef' every time when my buffer is updated, then with `[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];` I redraw the image manually. I'm quite sure there's better solutions, I'm open for all discussions.

Answer (score 1):

```
RemoteScreenController.m
- (void) setMappedPtr:(unsigned char *)ptr {

    m_mappedPtr = ptr;
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * 1680;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, m_mappedPtr, 1680*1050*4, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();      
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate( 1680, 1050, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, 
                                                                                bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    myView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
```

In my data manager class I have a reference to `RemoteScreenController`. When the first buffer is received, it calls `setMappedPtr` to initialize the image and add it to the view. Then the buffer is updated by another class.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CGImageCreate()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000956-CH1g-F17167), which can then be used to create a proper UIImage (`[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage]`) from your raw data. Then create a UIImageView and add it to a UIView for display.

For OpenGL, a CGImage should be all you need (as in [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html) example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I've tried with `CGImageCreate()`, I've create a `CGImageRef` by using a `CGDataProviderRef` which handles my buffer. But my image isn't redraw on the screen when my buffer is modified.

Comment: If that approach fails, I bet the problem is somewhere else. Can you post some actual code which shows the problem?

Comment: I've also read the example for OpenGL. In **the UIImage Approach** paragraph, if I've understood correctly OpenGL makes a copy of the image-related data, so in my case my buffer will be copied my OpenGL, instead of handle the pointer as I wished.

Comment: Yes, well you have to load the texture into the graphics device memory each time you change it. This will essentially be an "animated" texture, so you might want to look into how that can best be performed in opengl. Just curious, why are you doing this with OpenGL and not just using plain old UIVIew or CGLayers?

Comment: Because the app isn't a simple VNC client but a light client for a 3D-visualization application. To display RAW images is just a very first step. Ideally the app receives OpenGL textures from the server and doing the mapping stuffs by using OpenGL ES. So I must eventually deal with OpenGL. I hope I've made my self clearly.